# Newbie trying to construct an URL for GET request - my test code and screenshot included

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

Being an iOS and Objective-C newbie I'm trying to construct an app, where the user can authenticate through Facebook, Google+ or 3 further (Russian) social networks.

For Facebook I know, that I could use the Facebook SDK or Social.framework, but for the others - I have to use OAuth and `UIWebView`, because there are no good SDKs for them yet.

(I have already succeeded in that once - but that was for an Adobe AIR app and now I'm trying to learn native...)

In Xcode 5.2 I have prepared a very simple Master-Detail app for iPhone and [checked it into GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyAuth):

[image: screenshot]

My question is about constructing a NSString for a GET (or body in POST) request -

Currently I have the following awkward source code in [the DetailViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyAuth/MyAuth/DetailViewController.m):

```
- (NSString*)buildUrl
{
    NSString *key = _dict[kKey];
    NSString *str = _dict[kAuthUrl];

    if ([key isEqual: kFB]) {
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"display=touch"];
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"&response_time=token"];
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"&client_id="];
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:_dict[kAppId]];
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"&redirect_uri="];
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:_dict[kAppUrl]];
        //str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"&state="];
        //str = [str stringByAppendingString:rand(1000)];
    } else if ([key isEqual: kGG]) {
    } else if ([key isEqual: kMR]) {
    } else if ([key isEqual: kOK]) {
    } else if ([key isEqual: kVK]) {
    }

    return str;
}
```

**My questions:**

1. Instead of using `stringByAppendingString` could I use something nicer? Like maybe an NSArray (or even better NSDictionary) and then somehow joining it with ampersands inbetween?
2. How to escape the HTML entities in the value of `redirect_uri=` ?
3. I need to append a random number as the value of `state=`, but I am not sure what function to use there best...

Here is what [my app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyAuth) prints at the moment, for the above code:

MyAuth[9626:70b] request:  { URL: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?display=touch&response_time=token&client_id=432298283565593&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html }

(which is no good: the URL at the end is not escaped and there is no random state number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringWithFormat:` is your friend.

```
- (NSString*)buildUrl
{
    NSString *key = _dict[kKey];
    NSString *str = _dict[kAuthUrl];

    if ([key isEqual: kFB]) {
        NSString *escapedURI = [_dict[kAppUrl] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
        int state = arc4random_uniform(1000);
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@display=touch&response_time=token&client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&state=%d", _dict[kAuthUrl], _dict[kAppId], escapedURI, state];
    } else if ([key isEqual: kGG]) {
    } else if ([key isEqual: kMR]) {
    } else if ([key isEqual: kOK]) {
    } else if ([key isEqual: kVK]) {
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks better than my code. So there is no nice method to join an `NSDictionary` to a `NSString`?

Comment: My answer shows a nice way to join a dictionary and a string.